# Why does git log throw fatal bad objects when hash is given?

Tags: git, shell

I've got a shell script that gets and exports a variable for these calls:
1. dev env "build id", 
2. dev env "git commit hash",
3. test env "git commit hash",
4. dev env version
5. test env version

```
export DEV_BUILD_ID=$(curl -k https://my-website-dev/version.txt | grep BUILD_ID=|cut -f2 -d"=")
echo 'This is DEV BUILD ID: '$DEV_BUILD_ID

export DEV_HASH=$(curl -k https://my-website-dev/version.txt | grep GIT_COMMIT=|cut -f2 -d"=")
echo 'This is DEV HASH: '$DEV_HASH 

export TST_HASH=$(curl -k https://my-website-test/version.txt | grep GIT_COMMIT=|cut -f2 -d"=")
echo 'This is TEST HASH: '$TST_HASH 

export DEV_VERSION=$(git log -1 --pretty=%h $DEV_HASH)
echo 'This is DEV VERSION: ' $DEV_VERSION

export TST_VERSION=$(git log -1 --pretty=%h $TST_HASH)
echo 'This is TEST VERSION: ' $TST_VERSION
```

and after all these, I log the revisions of dev builds since the last deploy to the test env using this script:

```
echo 'Logging the output to word doc...'
git log $TST_VERSION^..$DEV_VERSION > "C:/TEMP/Test_Build_Changes_$DEV_BUILD_ID.DOC"
```

The problem I am facing is, all of a sudden the script is throwing this error today:

```
$ C:/Users/ssharipo/Documents/Tuts/git_revision_practice.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   372  100   372    0     0    722      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   745
This is DEV BUILD ID: 23
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   372  100   372    0     0    745      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   745
This is DEV HASH: 6c663e00a6e808476fe4cf4b7fa0af999ef27f5f
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   372  100   372    0     0    681      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   768
This is TEST HASH: 6c663e00a6e808476fe4cf4b7fa0af999ef27f5f
fatal: bad object 6c663e00a6e808476fe4cf4b7fa0af999ef27f5f
This is DEV VERSION:
fatal: bad object 6c663e00a6e808476fe4cf4b7fa0af999ef27f5f
This is TEST VERSION:
Logging the output to word doc...
fatal: bad revision '^..'
```

**Any ideas how to fix this issue?**

Comment: well, this is quite obvious that git does not know about 6c663e00a6e808476fe4cf4b7fa0af999ef27f5f, so the question is: Why do YOU think it should know it?

Answer (score 1):

Your shell script has a fundamental flaw: it calls up some web site and asks that web site for a hash ID of a Git object, as recorded at the web site.  Then, having obtained that hash ID, you ask *your* Git to show you that object.

If your Git has that object for some other reason, your Git can show you the object.  But in that case, one might wonder why you are consulting some web site in the first place.  If your Git does *not* have the object, the web site's information about Git hash IDs is not useful, and one *should* wonder why you are consulting some web site in the first place.

As an analogy, this is like asking Bob what Jack is doing, and then having heard from Bob, asking Fred to show you what Jack is doing.  (Whether this analogy really holds up depends on your situation, which you have not really described.)

It's also not obvious how to repair the problem.  If the web site you're consulting obtains its Git hash IDs from some other Git repository, probably the approach to use is to have your Git run `git fetch` to that other Git, obtaining both the hash IDs *and* the objects all at once.  (Using the same analogy, this is like going straight to Jack to find out what he's doing.)

Answer (score -2):

When I was running this script, I was checked out to Master's branch. But this script needs to be run against the branch the build was executed against. So, I checked out Dev branch and ran this script everything worked fine.

Comment: Nope, you didn't have those objects in your repo at all, checking out your branch didn't do it, fetching them from whatever repo your website was looking at (or any other that has those objects) is what did it.